# Unable to cast .Net ConcurrentDictionary<K,V> to IReadOnlyDictionary<K,V> interface?

Tags: c#, interface

I must be missing something and feel like I have to go back to the very basics but [according to the reference sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,60) for ConcurrentDictionary in .Net 4.5 it implements the IReadOnlyDictionary interface (albeit some members explicitely), but for some reason I cannot cast an instance to that interface - why is that?

```
IDictionary<int, string> a = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>(); // works
IReadOnlyDictionary<int, string> b = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>(); // does not work
```

.. why is that?

To make this a bit more clear:

[image]

Comment: The source code you are referencing is for .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: Yacoub - I know but the interface(s) at least the IReadOnlyDictionary one, is in 4.5.1 (which the project is targeting) already, too.. the link IS just for reference.. I could also linked to MSDN etc..

Comment: If you download the source code of .NET 4.5.1, you will see that ConcurrentDictionary does not implement that interface

Answer (score 7):

You probably use .NET version where this interface is not implemented by the [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.100).aspx). From what I have tried it is not implemented by .NET versions before 4.6:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(false)]
[HostProtectionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Synchronization = true, 
    ExternalThreading = true)]
public class ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
    ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, 
    IDictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

In current .NET framework version (4.6.2) the [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) implements it:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(false)]
[HostProtectionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Synchronization = true, 
    ExternalThreading = true)]
public class ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
    ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, 
    IEnumerable, IDictionary, ICollection, IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
    IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
```

Comment: The project is targeting 4.5.1 which does list the interface for ConcurrentDictionary, too ... that's why I am confused. See http://imgur.com/SAru0oV

Comment: @JörgB. Hmm, perhaps there is an error in .NET documentation. But in 4.5.1 it seems to not implement it, while the next 4.6 version implements it.

Answer (score 6):

Well as it turns out a combo of .Net 4.6 being an in-place update and Resharper's 'Navigate to Sources' tricked me here -.-

Even though the project targets 4.5(.1), when navigating to the ConcurrentDictionary Sources (and being offline) R# fell back to 'decompiling' the assembly - and as .Net 4.6 replaces 4.5 altogether with its assemblies, R# "presented" the incorrect assemblies to me & I incorrectly assumed 4.5(.1) to already implement the IReadOnlyCollection interface, too. Meh.

Those in-place .Net updates really are somewhat confusing sometimes.

Oh well - thanks Eugene / Yacoub for making me triple check my source(s).

Comment: I had the same Resharper navigate to source and .NET 4.5.x problem. This post saved me a ton of time. Thanks!